# Dumb MS Access Q: Query based on other queries

Tags: ms-access

I have been trying to run a report for my CEO that shows income. Our agency management software uses FoxPro databases (it originally came out in the early '80s, I think). I have linked the .dbf files to an Access database, and I have been setting up queries based on queries to get the information I need on a live basis without having to export the data. The problem that I have run into is that I cleaned up the selection criteria in the first query, but I did not run that query (it takes about ten minutes to run each of these). When I ran the last query (with data based on the first), I still had bad data in that result.

So here's the dumb question: (a) do I need to create a macro that runs the queries (there are four of them) in sequence so that they are all updated each time, (b) is there some better way to do this, and/or (c) does Access automatically run the prior queries when I run the downstream query?

Comment: Are your queries 'chained' together (i.e. Qry2 uses Qry1 as input; Qry4 uses Qry3)? If not, do your queries create tables that are then used later?

Comment: (c)  Access will run your upstream queries (as long as they are queries and not Tables as @WayneG.Dunn is alluding to)

Comment: You may want to have the first query get just the data you need from FoxPro and put it into a local access table and then run the next three queries off of that.  This way if queries 2 - 4 use features that require access to examine each row of query 1, access won't have to re-examine the FoxPro data row by row.

Comment: Like others said, it depends on whether your queries are `SELECT` queries or action queries. If they are action queries you have to manually (or via macro) run them. If they are SELECT queries running one query will also run all of its sub-queries.

Comment: First-my apologies-I did not get any notifications saying that anyone had responded, so I figured it was too dumb a question to merit responses. Thanks, spam blocker. Second, thank you all for your responses and suggestions. They are all SELECT queries, and the idea of creating the Access Table is likely to save a boatload of time on rerunning things. Again, hugely appreciated!